# Implement a "do not disturb / distract me" mode in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, contentcontrol

I want to implement a "do not disturb" mode in my application. Basically they enable this mode, and we block certain applications like MSN / Skype / etc from disrupting the users' focus.

It's an online game and some users have requested this and we'd like to experiment trying it.

I am not sure where to start. **Does Windows have a global "busy" mode** that apps like Skype are sensitive to? I have heard about [Windows Presentation Mode](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/10/28/windows-presentation-mode.aspx), but I think it only gets us half way there.

Otherwise, **is there a good-bear way to programmatically set Skype / IM apps to "busy"**?

Comment: What game is this, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any general mechanism, but it looks like the [Skype Public API](http://developer.skype.com/accessories) supports this (e.g. setting user to "do not disturb").

Looks like you may have to code for various specific IM client APIs, unfortunately.